# VBA Script loops in all sheets but doesn't produce output in all sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

This VBA script I have loops through all sheets but I don't see the output in all sheets. What would be the reason be?

```
Sub A()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Dim ct As String
ct = ws.Range("H4").Text
If InStr(1, ct, "CELL") Then
For Each B In ws.Range("B7:B49").Cells
    If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then
        Cells(B.Row, 9) = Trim(Cells(B.Row + 1, 8)) & Trim(Cells(B.Row + 2, 8))
        Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) = ""
        Cells(B.Row + 2, 8) = ""
    If B.Row > 50 Then Exit For
End If
Next B
For Each C In ws.Range("C1:C50").Cells
    If Cells(C.Row, C.Column - 1) = "" Then
        Cells(C.Row, C.Column) = ""
    End If
Next C
For Each D In ws.Range("D1:D50").Cells
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column) = ""
Next D
For Each E In ws.Range("E1:E50").Cells
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column) = ""
Next E
For Each F In ws.Range("F1:F50").Cells
    Cells(F.Row, F.Column) = ""
Next F
For Each G In ws.Range("G1:G50").Cells
    Cells(G.Row, G.Column) = ""
Next G
For Each D In ws.Range("D1:D50").Cells
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column) = Cells(D.Row, D.Column + 4)
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column + 4) = ""
Next D
For Each E In ws.Range("E1:E50").Cells
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column) = Cells(E.Row, E.Column + 4)
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column + 4) = ""
Next E
End If


Dim cat As String
cat = ws.Range("I4").Text
If InStr(1, cat, "CELL") Then
For Each B In ws.Range("B7:B49").Cells
    If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then
        Cells(B.Row, 10) = Trim(Cells(B.Row + 1, 9)) & Trim(Cells(B.Row + 2, 9))
        Cells(B.Row + 1, 9) = ""
        Cells(B.Row + 2, 9) = ""
    If B.Row > 50 Then Exit For
End If
Next B
For Each C In ws.Range("C1:C50").Cells
    If Cells(C.Row, C.Column - 1) = "" Then
        Cells(C.Row, C.Column) = ""
    End If
Next C
For Each D In ws.Range("D1:D50").Cells
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column) = ""
Next D
For Each E In ws.Range("E1:E50").Cells
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column) = ""
Next E
For Each F In ws.Range("F1:F50").Cells
    Cells(F.Row, F.Column) = ""
Next F
For Each G In ws.Range("G1:G50").Cells
    Cells(G.Row, G.Column) = ""
Next G
For Each M In ws.Range("H1:H50").Cells
    Cells(M.Row, M.Column) = ""
Next M
For Each D In ws.Range("D1:D50").Cells
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column) = Cells(D.Row, D.Column + 5)
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column + 5) = ""
Next D
For Each E In ws.Range("E1:E50").Cells
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column) = Cells(E.Row, E.Column + 5)
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column + 5) = ""
Next E
End If



Dim cate As String
cate = ws.Range("J4").Text
If InStr(1, cate, "CELL") Then
For Each B In ws.Range("B7:B49").Cells
    If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then
        Cells(B.Row, 11) = Trim(Cells(B.Row + 1, 10)) & Trim(Cells(B.Row + 2, 10))
        Cells(B.Row + 1, 10) = ""
        Cells(B.Row + 2, 10) = ""
    If B.Row > 50 Then Exit For
End If
Next B
For Each C In ws.Range("C1:C50").Cells
    If Cells(C.Row, C.Column - 1) = "" Then
        Cells(C.Row, C.Column) = ""
    End If
Next C
For Each D In ws.Range("D1:D50").Cells
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column) = ""
Next D
For Each E In ws.Range("E1:E50").Cells
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column) = ""
Next E
For Each F In ws.Range("F1:F50").Cells
    Cells(F.Row, F.Column) = ""
Next F
For Each G In ws.Range("G1:G50").Cells
    Cells(G.Row, G.Column) = ""
Next G
For Each M In ws.Range("H1:H50").Cells
    Cells(M.Row, M.Column) = ""
Next M
For Each I In ws.Range("I1:I50").Cells
    Cells(I.Row, I.Column) = ""
Next I
For Each J In ws.Range("J1:J50").Cells
    Cells(J.Row, J.Column) = ""
Next J
For Each D In ws.Range("D1:D50").Cells
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column) = Cells(D.Row, D.Column + 6)
    Cells(D.Row, D.Column + 6) = ""
Next D
For Each E In ws.Range("E1:E50").Cells
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column) = Cells(E.Row, E.Column + 6)
    Cells(E.Row, E.Column + 6) = ""
Next E
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

What could the reason be for it to loop through the worksheets and yet not produce the output in the [ages

Answer (score 1):

You get content from the various worksheets, but you do not change content for the various worksheets.

In your script, you refer to ws for the worksheet, but lateron you use Cells(..) to set its content. You would need to add ws. in front of it, so your code shows as ws.cells(..., ...) = ""

Comment: @Rathan, please see http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers Thanks.